# Java Weka: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, weka, cross-validation

I working on this simple experiment on Weka. I trying to do simple cross-validation and I got this error. Below is the error message generate from the output.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.AbstractOutput
at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1471)
at assg.Assg.crossValidation(Assg.java:171)
at assg.Assg.main(Assg.java:160)
```

Below is my coding

```
public static void crossValidation() throws Exception
{
    eval.evaluateModel(cls, training, 10, new Random(1));
    System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString());
}
```

Comment: What attempts did you make to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: My apologies... I call the wrong method to run cross-validation... I am sorry about that. My bad...

Answer (score 0):

Did you even read the error message and the docs for the function you're calling?

```
  /**
   * Evaluates the classifier on a given set of instances. Note that
   * the data must have exactly the same format (e.g. order of
   * attributes) as the data used to train the classifier! Otherwise
   * the results will generally be meaningless.
   *
   * @param classifier machine learning classifier
   * @param data set of test instances for evaluation
   * @param forPredictionsPrinting varargs parameter that, if supplied, is
   * expected to hold a weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.AbstractOutput
   * object
   * @return the predictions
   * @throws Exception if model could not be evaluated
   * successfully
   */
  public double[] evaluateModel(Classifier classifier,
                                Instances data,
                                Object... forPredictionsPrinting)
```

You're passing a primative int (Which is autoboxed to `java.lang.Integer`) as an argument to a function which is expecting a `weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.AbstractOutput`. You're obviously going to get a casting error since the types aren't compatible.